# Making CORS with AngularJS with Cookie

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, cookies, cors

I'm using AngularJS 1.4.7.
What I want to do is to make a cross origin request with JSON payload (application/json) with Cookie header, too.

I read different options and suggestions and still my cookie and the content type are not set.

And I'm getting **Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"** error message.

I try to add the "withCredentials:true" to the config but without success.

```js
mod.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
});
```

```js
$http({
    withCredentials: true,
    method: POST,
    url: url,
    data: jsondata,
    timeout: deferred.promise,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=am1miv3koldaqh0ppf9r75hdg1',
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the cookie header manually for an XHR object. That is a firm rule (see Step 5 of the [addRequestHeader](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method) process) and you can't change it with CORS.

If you want to set a cookie on a different origin, then you need to have that origin set it using an HTTP response.